# How to curl elastic or kibana api for alerts?

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I am learning to use the ELK stack. Both kibana and elasticsearch are installed on my localhost. I just learnt how to install metricbeat and how to set up alerts. When setting up the alerts, I used the index connector, and called my index testconnector.

I see the alerts showing up in my web browser when i go to `http://localhost:5601/app/observability/alerts`.

Is there a way for me to get the same information via REST API? i tried all these endpoints but they all say "no handler found for uri"

```
curl -X GET -k -u elasticuser:elasticpass "http://localhost:9200/api/index_management/indices"
curl -X GET -k -u elasticuser:elasticpass "http://localhost:9200/api/alert"
curl -X GET -k -u elasticuser:elasticpass "http://localhost:9200/api/alert/_search"
curl -X GET -k -u elasticuser:elasticpass "http://localhost:9200/api/alert/_find"
curl -X GET -k -u elasticuser:elasticpass "http://localhost:9200/alert/_search"
curl -X GET -k -u elasticuser:elasticpass "http://localhost:9200/alert/_find"
curl -X GET -k -u elasticuser:elasticpass "http://localhost:9200/kibana/api/alerting"
curl -X GET -k -u elasticuser:elasticpass "http://localhost:9200/testconnector/_search"
```

If anyone can tell me how to get the alerts (not the rules) through a REST API, that will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  First, you can get a list of all the rules from **kibana api** (as opposed to elastic api) like this:

```
curl -X GET -k -u elasticuser:elasticpass "http://localhost:5601/api/alerting/rules/_find"
```

The list of rules also contains some execution status of each rule.  Meaning some are active, some are ok, some are recovered etc... So right off the bat, I have what I need related to the alerts associated with each rule.

If I need more details, I can grab the rule id and get more details with this curl

```
curl -X GET -k -u elasticuser:elasticpass "http://localhost:5601/api/alerting/rule/<rule id>"
```

All the API endpoints for rule and alert management can be found here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/alerting-apis.html